# How do database connections get managed for Spring Data JPA repositories?

Tags: jpa, transactions, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a question about how Spring Data repositories are handling the datasource connections. Assuming Spring Data repositories open and close the connection and the connection when the method executes, how does the transaction started by declaring `@Transactional` in my service layer span across multiple repository calls?

Who handles the database connections? The `@Transactional` annotation or the JPA repository?

Answer (score 4):

### tl;dr

Ultimately it's the Spring JPA / Transaction infrastructure managing the connection via the thead-bound management of `EntityManager` instances. The scope of the transaction is controlled by `@Transactional` annotations in the user code but ultimately defaulted in Spring Data JPA's repository implementation. Connection acquisition is performed eagerly in case an `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` is used (enabled by default in Spring Boot 1.x and 2.x).

### Details

[`SimpleJpaRepository`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/0944dae115424cb1512e6f3fd8fd9b8f5a4e0442/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java) is equipped with Spring's `@Transactional` annotations so that it will make sure it runs transactions in cases JPA requires them (e.g. to execute a call to `EntityManager.persist(…)` or `….merge(…)`). Their default configuration makes sure, they automatically take part in transactions started at higher levels of abstraction. I.e. if you have a Spring component that's `@Transactional` itself, repositories will simply participate in the already running transaction:

```
@Component
class MyService {

  private final FirstRepository first;
  private final SecondRepository second;

  // Constructor omitted for brevity

  @Transactional
  void someMethod() {

     … = first.save(…);
     … = second.save(…);
  }
}
```

Both repositories participate in the transaction and a failure in one of them will roll back the entire transaction.

To achieve that, the `JpaTransactionManager` will use the transaction management API exposed by JPA's `EntityManager` to start a transaction and acquire a connection for the lifetime of the `EntityManager` instance. See [`JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(…)`](https://github.com/philwebb/spring-framework/blob/5c7ac514b79fbde2c3fd3c695385dab24aff08b4/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTransactionManager.java#L354-L433) for details.

### The role of an `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` or `–Interceptor`

Unless explicitly deactivated, Spring Boot 1.x and 2.x web applications run with an `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` deployed. Its used to create an `EntityManager` and thus acquire a connection pretty early and keep it around until very late in the request processing, namely after the view has been rendered. This has the effect of JPA lazy-loading being available to the view rendering but keeps the connection open for longer than if it was only needed for the actual transactional work.

That topic is quite a [controversial one](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7107) as its a tricky balance between developer convenience (the ability to traverse object relations to loaded lazily in the view rendering phase) at the risk of exactly that triggering expensive additional queries and keeping the resources in use for a longer time.

Comment: Hi Oliver, Thanks for the explanation. So OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter is active for Lazy loading even if the response is in Json/Xml format right?

Comment: I agree that i shouldn't use the entity for the response conversion

Comment: Most of the times, the responses get rendered based on some entity state, e.g. the entity might just be forwarded to Jackson for JSON marshalling. In those cases, you'd have to make sure that associations are traversable during the rendering.

Comment: Does it not impact the service latency as all the lazy collections are initialized during json serialization in case the Jpa Entities are used?